# Reduce data but preserving order in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following database

```
ID_car, latitude, longitude, time (timestamp)
```

I want to reduce data to get difference between points made by the car **on the same latitude** (just for an example), for instance, if I have:

```
1, 10, 20, 1020
1, 10, 22, 1001
1, 10, 23, 1000
```

First I need to sort for timestamp, then, I would like to reduce data to get diff between longitudes:

```
data.sortBy(lambda row: row[2]) \
.reduce(lambda x, y: y[2] - x[2])
```

But Spark **doesn't preserve order of data**, so, I couldn't say that *y* was later than *x*.

Is there a way to make a reduce of data in Spark, but preserving the order?

**Real data:**

```
ID  Lat Lon Timestamp Dest
905 28  28  8079
905 28  27  8088
905 27  27  8097
905 26  27  8006
905 25  27  8115
905 24  27  8124       School
```

**Real problem:**

**I need to get the straight stretch longer run**, so, I need to order by time, because maybe the car turn on right/left and It's no straight anymore.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English

Comment: First, are you sure this sample code works? `data.sortBy(lambda row: row[2]) \
.reduce(lambda x, y: y[2] - x[2])`

Comment: You can use window functions to preserve order. partitionBy latitude, orderBy time then use lead or lag to get reduce

Comment: I sort after the reducing - that seems a better strategy in light if the way Spark works.

Comment: @Prazy, thanks for the atention, It is just an example, real code is more complex. The question is about ruduce with order, not about a code not working

Comment: @sramalingam24, I don't know window functions, I'm going to read about it

Comment: @thebluephantom, If I reduce with disordered data It throw wrong results as expected, I need to get the diff only between contiguous samples

Comment: It would be cool if people that downvote leave a comment about why my question is not valid so I could clarify the details so that the question is better understood

Comment: I did not downvote

Comment: Nono, I'm not blaming you! I'm saying to whom it corresponds :D

Comment: I upvoted to remove it, it was probably because this is an often asked question about preserving order after grouping in spark but yeah they should make it mandatory to comment for downvotes

Comment: Show some more data and output and I will look

Comment: It can be solved but we need some data

Comment: Are you interested in an answer still?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't have internet access, I've edited my question. Thank you for your predisposition! :)